# Cataloging web/db/app servers in an organisation - Excel/Wiki/?

Tags: configuration, configuration-management

I've inherited "ownership" of various servers (the hardware itself and server software that runs on in - lots of Apache/Oracle/MySQL) with a wide variety of configurations. I'm a developer - I've been thrown into a Team Leader/Systems Support role for some very unfortunate reasons.

Do any of you guys in the SysAdmin world have any tricks/templates? So far, I've got an Excel spreadsheet with columns

```
HOST  IP   PORT  USE     POC 
----  --   ----  ---     ---
db1   x.x  1521  Oracle  Joe
```

Not rocket science, and what I've got will do the job once it's complete, but once it's got everything in there it's going to be pretty busy. There are probably ~ 30 hosts, but anywhere between 1-20 server apps on each machine.

My question essentially is "how do you guys do it"? Is there a magic Excel template I should adapt? Do you just use a Wiki and keep it udpated? Is this SysAdmin 101?

New to this.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has their own way of documenting things. First you need to make it so it is usable by you replacement. Second by you.

I don't like excel for server documentation, there is just too much information that you need to track to keep it sane. I do keep a seperate excel spreadsheet with the following info:
*  IP
*  Hostname
*  Owner
*  Function

Each subnet gets a separate tab.

I'm a big fan of writin documentation in <Advanced document editor of choice>. Personally I keep one monolithic Word document, using headings so that a ToC can be auto-generated.  Wiki's also work well since you can break things down and have less clutter but still the same info. I personally don't like them because they are a PITA to keep updated in an offline form.

What I keep for each server:

- Servername
- Any historical server names
- function
- IP
- Physical location
- Hardware
- OS
- Installed Software

  - Configuration information (who,what,when,why,how)
- Custom scripts - location and function

  - Simple scripts have a flow diagram built in
  - complex scripts have their own process documentation
- Backup Information